# Django REST API Media URL Problems

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when I send a get request to a question with rest api in django.
It looks like "image": "question_images/myphoto.png",
But I also want the media folder to appear like "image": "media/question_images/myphoto.png", how can this be achieved? question_images located in the media folder.

I configured MEDIA_URL.

Comment: Please show related model definition (with ImageField), settings.py part related to media files and elaborate who/what generates URLs you mentioned in the question. _Show the code_.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check with your code (this configuration for save image in media folder)

## Add Code in Project (urls.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from django.conf import settings # --------> this
from django.conf.urls.static import static # --------> this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # --------> this
```

## Add Code in Project (setting.py)

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  BASE_DIR / 'media' 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```